# Why are 'not equals' queries in firestore not supported/hard to implement?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI) does a great job explaining the reason behind query limitations in Firestore. The major takeaway is that the results of a query have to be consecutive in the index for the query to be supported.

To perform a != query, why couldn't you perform an = query, grab the resulting start and end points in the index, and then return all documents outside this range in the index?

**In Short**
Why does the != index not qualify as performant in Firestore?

Comment: One of the reasons is that documents that don't have (a value for that) field are not in the index.

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for the insight. My quick take is omitting those documents would be an acceptable compromise to the query-er.

Comment: But how do you know which documents should be omitted?  Scanning the entire collection is unacceptable for performance reasons, as there may be trillions of documents in the collection.  Firestore will refuse to do anything without an index.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. I'm definitely not qualified to actually suggest the solution, this is more of a curiosity question, but I thought Frank just said those documents won't be in the index - so why worry about them?

Comment: All I see is that the suggested workaround is to combine a > and < query, it seemed like that should not be a necessary workaround given the explanation in the video on indexes

Comment: This feature has been implemented in [v7.21.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-firestore). I would love to hear from the developers how they managed to overcome the limitations discussed in the comments here.